# Opening a page popup on ajax success

Tags: javascript, java, php, mysql

I am doing a project and im having problem with window.open. The problem is window.open doesnt work in my schema. i need a help on this,

```
swal({
    title: "Submit Data ?",
    text: "Process only if you are sure",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, Submit!",
    cancelButtonText: "No, Cancel!",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false
},
function(isConfirm){
    if (isConfirm) {
        insertData();
        swal("SUCCESS", "Data Has Been Submitted", "success");
        window.open("http://188.109.156.21/execution.php?str=james");
    } else {
        swal("CANCELLED", "", "error");
    }
});

function insertData(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "../../../html/main/divpages/submit_data.php",
        data: sentReq,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (response.indexOf("GAGAL") == -1) {
                window.location.href = "main.php";
            } else {
                alert("GAGAL INSERT");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

so i can execute insertData() with no problem.but the problem lies when executin windows.open inside swal(). i dont see any window popup is opening.

Comment: You never call `swal` anywhere. Could you also please show us what that function does?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

Comment: @MisterM helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the popup-blocking logic in action that browsers use. You have to attach window.open directly on onClick event.

Use something like this:

```
var checkSuccess = false;

$('#button').on("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "your url",
      async:false,
      success: function(){ 
         checkSuccess = true;
         //YOUR LOGIC
      }
    });
    if(checkSuccess){
      window.open("http://188.109.156.21/execution.php?str=james");
    }
})
```

Comment: well actually all of those are inside a function submitData() and the trigger is <button class="btn btn-block" onclick="SubmitData();">SUBMIT</button>

Comment: You have to use window.open directly during click action, or most probably browsers will block it. Then after ajax success you can just change its location.